Non reduced anticommutative ring
Reduced ring: A ring $R$ is said to be reduced if it has no non-zero nilpotent elements.
Anticommutative ring: A ring $R$ is said to be anticommutative if $xy=-yx$ for all $x,y\in R$.
I am trying to find an example of a ring which is not reduced but anticommutative. For example $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is anticommutative but reduced also, so it will not work. Any hint?

$R=\Bigg\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0 \\
a & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}|a \in \mathbb{R}
\Bigg\rbrace$.
This ring is clearly non reduced but anticommutative.

How about $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2)$?

what is the characteristic of this ring?

$2$; this ring is both commutative and anticommutative.
